# How do I get the slide in as you scroll down (CSS Trick) technique to work in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, webkit, css-animations

I'm trying a technique described on CSS Tricks:
http://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/

I'm a bit stumped on this one... When I view the technique on the CSS Tricks website in Safari, it works fine... However, when I try the code out, I can't get it to work on Safari... Works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Anyone have any ideas?
I greatly appreciate some extra eyes on this, because I've been staring at this way too long.

Thanks in advance.

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/pjbsL1mk/1/

The code is pretty much verbatim, except that I added "-webkit-" along side the original code to the classes... Also, I'm using jQuery 1.8.3.

```
.come-in {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(150px);
    -webkit-animation: come-in 1s ease forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    transform: translateY(150px);
    animation: come-in 1s ease forwards;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
  animation-duration: 0.6s; /* So they look staggered */
}

.already-visible {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-animation: none;
    transform: translateY(0);
    animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes come-in {
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);   
    }
} 

@keyframes come-in {
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough posts to add an image of what it looks like in Safari, but what happens is that as you scroll down the page, the boxes never slide up, so there is a gap between the already visible boxes at the top and the ".modules" that are supposed to slide up.

Comment: Also, I'm using Safari 7.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `-webkit-` prefix on some properties:

```
@-webkit-keyframes come-in {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);   // here
    }
}
```

This should make the animation work. Also add `-webkit-` here:

```
.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s; // here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate the extra eyes... I'm not sure how I missed that... Here's the updated fiddle, if it would help anyone: http://jsfiddle.net/pjbsL1mk/3/